# Difficulty taking info from JSON page and putting into MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Ok.. I'm trying to get info from an external JSON page into my local MySQL database (via xampp). It's not working.. Here is my code.

**JSON PAGE**

```
{
        "id": 219,
        "first_name": "Dimitar",
        "second_name": "Berbatov",
    "season_history": [
        ["2006/07", 2715, 12, 11, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 26, 0, 91, 169],
        ["2007/08", 2989, 15, 11, 0, 56, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 18, 0, 95, 177],
        ["2008/09", 2564, 9, 10, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 14, 0, 95, 138],
        ["2009/10", 2094, 12, 6, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 92, 130],
        ["2010/11", 2208, 21, 4, 8, 28, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 26, 0, 92, 176],
        ["2011/12", 521, 7, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 146, 89, 49]
}
```

**mycode.php**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("SERVER","USERNAME","PASSWORD", "DATABASE") or die("Nope.");

//GETS THE PAGE WITH THE PLAYER DETAILS
$i = 219; //will loop this for every user later
$str = file_get_contents('http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/'.$i.'/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

//PLAYER DETAILS
$id = $jsonarray['id'];
$firstname = addslashes($jsonarray['first_name']);
$secondname = addslashes($jsonarray['second_name']);

//Count how many seasons
$numberOfSeasons = count($jsonarray['season_history']);

//For Each Season
for($SeasonCount = 0; $SeasonCount < $numberOfSeasons; $SeasonCount++) {
    $whichSeason = $jsonarray['season_history'][$SeasonCount][0];
    $SeasonMins = $jsonarray['season_history'][$SeasonCount][1];
    $SeasonGoalsScored = $jsonarray['season_history'][$SeasonCount][2];
    $SeasonAssists = $jsonarray['season_history'][$SeasonCount][3];

mysqli_query
($con, "
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE id='$id' AND whichSeason='$whichSeason')
UPDATE myTable SET 
    id = '$id', 
    whichSeason = '$whichSeason',
    SeasonMins = '$SeasonMins', 
    SeasonGoalsScored = '$SeasonGoalsScored', 
    SeasonAssists = '$SeasonAssists'
ELSE
INSERT INTO myTable (id, whichSeason, SeasonMins, SeasonGoalsScored, SeasonAssists) 
VALUES ('$id', '$whichSeason', '$SeasonMins', '$SeasonGoalsScored', '$SeasonAssists')
")
or die (mysqli_error($con));

}
```

**NOTE**

- There is no primary key. I don't know what entry could be used as one.

**WHAT IT SHOULD DO**

- Search `myTable` to see if an entry already exists.
- If no match, add it.
- If it's already there, update it.

Please let me know if you need any more information. I don't know anything about PDO, but as this database is local and the page is run on my browser only, I don't need it right?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: is your query working

Comment: No. I had a simpler query which puts in the data, but every time it is run, it just duplicates the data rather than updating it.

Comment: @DevZer0 This worked - What I had was: mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO myTable (id, whichSeason, SeasonMins, SeasonGoalsScored, SeasonAssists) VALUES ('$id', '$whichSeason', '$SeasonMins', '$SeasonGoalsScored', '$SeasonAssists')") or die (mysqli_error($con));

Comment: what is unique in your table.. what has to match for it to be an update as opposed to an insert?

Comment: There is no single unique item in this table. each `id` and `whichSeason` should only have 1 entry. for example, one player id may have 5 seasons.

Comment: that should be your primary key then (or at least a unique key) ... `alter table myTable add unique key (id, whichSeason);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using mysql you should be able to use and [replace into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) query.

First off you want to add a primary key on id and whichSeason

```
 ALTER TABLE myTable add primary key (id, whichSeason);
```

Then you can issue the replace into query.

```
REPLACE INTO myTable 
    (id, whichSeason, SeasonMins, SeasonGoalsScored, SeasonAssists) 
VALUES 
    ('$id', '$whichSeason', '$SeasonMins', '$SeasonGoalsScored', '$SeasonAssists');
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. it worked perfectly. My internet cut off last night so I couldn't sort it, but it's working perfectly now. Congrats on 10k :)